# crow probability problem

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem, but am having some difficulty. Can anyone give me some guidance?

> There are lots of tourists in Grandeville. The streets in Grandeville run
>   east to west and go from
>
> ```
> ..., S. 2nd St., S. 1st St., Broadway St., N. 1st St., N. 2nd St., ...
> ```
>
> The avenues run north to south and go from
>
> ```
> ..., E. 2nd Ave., E. 1st Ave., Broadway Ave., W. 1st Ave., W. 2nd Ave., ...
> ```
>
> These streets form a square block grid. For each of the questions
>   below, the tourist starts at the intersection of Broadway St. and
>   Broadway Avenue and moves one block in each of the four cardinal
>   directions with equal probability.

**Q1)** What is the probability that the tourist is at least 3 city blocks (as
the crow flies) from Broadway and Broadway after 10 moves?

**Q2)** What is the probability that the tourist is at least 10 city blocks
(as the crow flies) from Broadway and Broadway after 60 moves?

**Q3)** What is the probability that the tourist is ever at least 5 city
blocks (as the crow flies) from Broadway and Broadway within 10 moves?

**Q4)** What is the probability that the tourist is ever at least 10 city
blocks (as the crow flies) from Broadway and Broadway within 60 moves?

**Q5)** What is the probability that the tourist is ever east of East 1st
Avenue but ends up west of West 1st Avenue in 10 moves?

**Q6)** What is the probability that the tourist is ever east of East 1st
Avenue but ends up west of West 1st Avenue in 30 moves?

**Q7)** What is the average number of moves until the first time the tourist
is at least 10 city blocks (as the crow flies) from Broadway and
Broadway.

**Q8)** What is the average number of moves until the first time the tourist
is at least 60 city blocks (as the crow flies) from Broadway and
Broadway.

I am running this matlab code. But i am not sure how to find probabilities even to the first question?

```
function random_walk_2d_simulation ( step_num, walk_num )

%*****************************************************************************80
%
%% RANDOM_WALK_2D_SIMULATION simulates a random walk in 2D.
%
%  Discussion:
%
%    The expectation should be that, the average distance squared D^2 
%    is equal to the time, or number of steps N.
%
%    Or, equivalently
%
%      average ( D ) = sqrt ( N )
%
%    The program makes a plot of both the average and the maximum values
%    of D^2 versus time.  The maximum value grows much more quickly,
%    and that curve is much more jagged.
%
%  Licensing:
%
%    This code is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.
%
%  Modified:
%
%    03 November 2009
%
%  Author:
%
%    John Burkardt
%
%  Parameters:
%
%    Input, integer STEP_NUM, the number of steps to take in one test.
%
%    Input, integer WALK_NUM, the number of walks to take.
%

%
%  Set up arrays for plotting.
%
  time = 0 : step_num;
  d2_ave = zeros(step_num+1,1);
  d2_max = zeros(step_num+1,1);
%
%  Take the walk WALK_NUM times.
%
  for walk = 1 : walk_num

    x = zeros(step_num+1,1);
    y = zeros(step_num+1,1);

   for step = 2 : step_num + 1
%
%  We are currently at ( X(STEP-1), Y(STEP-1) ).
%  Consider the four possible points to step to.
%
      destination = [ x(step-1) + 1.0, y(step-1); ...
                      x(step-1) - 1.0, y(step-1); ...
                      x(step-1),       y(step-1) + 1.0; ...
                      x(step-1),       y(step-1) - 1.0 ];
%
%  Choose destination 1, 2, 3 or 4.
%
      k = ceil ( 4.0 * rand );
%
%  Move there.
%
      x(step) = destination(k,1);
      y(step) = destination(k,2);
%
%  Update the sum of every particle's distance at step J.
%
      d2 = x(step)^2 + y(step)^2;
      d2_ave(step) = d2_ave(step) + d2;
      d2_max(step) = max ( d2_max(step), d2 );

    end

  end
%
%  Average the squared distance at each step over all walks.
%
  d2_ave(:,1) = d2_ave(:,1) / walk_num;
%
%  Make a plot.
%
  clf
  plot ( time, d2_ave, time, d2_max, 'LineWidth', 2 );

  xlabel ( 'Time' )
  ylabel ( 'Distance squared' )
  title_string = sprintf ( '2D Random Walk Ave and Max - %d walks, %d steps', walk_num, step_num );
  title ( title_string );

  return
end
```

Here is the plot of running the following command
random_walk_2d_simulation(60,10000)

[image]

Comment: Are you supposed to answer this mathematically and exactly? Because you've asked in the wrong place. A computer simulation can only give approximate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) problem.  You could write a fairly simple random walk simulation which ends as soon as the tourist is 60 city blocks away from the starting location.  At any given time you only need to know the tourist's x,y coordinates.  Then each time-step, you pick a direction and increment either x or y.  You then need to keep track of distance from the origin (0,0).  Presumably this should be Euclidean distance, since it's all as the crow flies.

- decide direction to move
- update x,y and distance
- check if any of the distance requirements mentioned are met and store the timestep at which it occured
- if distance > 60 blocks, terminate

Comment: This fits better into the scope of Manhattan Distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), in my opinion.

Comment: The issue with Manhattan Distance, is that while that is a very logical distance to apply to this problem, the question specifically says "As the crow flies."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_crow_flies  In this two dimensional representation, this straight line would be measured by Euclidean distance (i.e. a crow can fly over buildings)

Comment: Hmm...good point! It's weird to measure crow flights in blocks!

Comment: @jamesmf. Thanks for your answer. I am wondering how probability is calculated in random walk simulation.  I mean how random walk simulation will be able to answer the 8 questions?

Comment: Run the simulation N times (N is a large number).  Then calculate the proportion of times that each thing occurred (or the average timestep at which each criterion was met).

Comment: @jamesmf. Thanks again. I will run it and post the code and result here so you can comment on it.

Comment: @jamesmf. The post is updated.

Comment: The code you're running is a random walk, and it's doing a lot of what you want.  You just need variables for each of the questions.  For the first question, you'd need to do a check on each of the first 10 steps seeing if the distance is greater than 3.  then you store that value (0 if they didn't, 1 if they did).  And you can average that over every iteration and that will get you a probability.

Comment: @jamesmf. I have added the plot

Comment: @jamesmf, What does "ever" signify in questions 3 to 6? What is the different between "ever" greater than or equal to 5 blocks and greater than or equal to 5 blocks? In other words, what is the difference between Q2 and Q4

Comment: to answer Q2 you need only know where the person is at time t=60.  to answer Q4, you need to keep track of whether or not the person ever got more than 10 blocks away at any t<60